# Router configuration - what does the NAT option mean?

Tags: routing

In my router I have this option:

[image]

I know what is NAT, but what does it mean the bridge option here? and how the NAT is related to it? what is more secured `enable` or `disabled` or `bridge`?

Answer (score 3):

Missing information: device brand and model.
My best guess at the moment:

Enable: device act as a router, external/WAN/ISP interface is connected to one subnet and internal/LAN interface to another. Outbound traffic from LAN to WAN is NATed behind external IP address.

Disable: device act as a router, external/WAN/ISP interface is connected to one subnet and internal/LAN interface to another. Outboud traffic from LAN to WAN is forwarded with original source IP address.

Bridge: device act as bridge/switch, and both  external/WAN/ISP interface and internal/LAN interface(s) are on the same network (broadcast domain).

Answer (score 1):

Bridge, I assume, is used for IPX/SPX over TCP/IP and what not. Network Address Translation is for using an internal network with one of the set-aside private blocks like 192.168.x.x, as opposed to classical routing which is a can of worms we will not get into.

Just use NAT.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your modem/ISP, which you haven't told us.

- [Some will require your router to do NAT, and will not work if you disable it](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/robin.d.h.walker/cmtips/homelan.html#homelan).
- [In other cases, the modem already does NAT.  "Double NAT" is horrible and will almost certainly break UPNP port forwarding, which is required for P2P protocols such as the  running a game server, sharing files through MSN messenger, BitTorrent etc](http://inmethod.com/forum/posts/list/908.page).